# What does `%*;` mean in SAS?

Tags: sas

I've come across a line of SAS code that looks like this today:

```
%*let var1=apple;
```

what does that mean? (is it a comment? or is it a macro? why the `%` sign?)

Comment: the aestricks(*) seems to be a typo, the`%` before let is required to declare any valriable that is not a part of any dataset.

Comment: the * isn't a typo - and as it turns out from the answer below that line of code is just a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Macro comments](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/a000543665.htm), created by prefixing a normal comment asterisk with a `%` as in the question, are subtly different from regular comments.

A regular comment, `*something;`, in a macro, will be processed by the macro tokenizer and the macro facility.  99% of the time, this doesn't matter; however, in some specific cases, this is a problem.

For example, if you want to comment out macro syntax, you must use the macro comment, otherwise it still takes effect:

```
%macro macvar_Test;
  %let macvar=ORIGINAL;
  *%let macvar=COMMENT;
  %*%let macvar=MACRO COMMENT;
  %put &=macvar;
%mend macvar_Test;

%macvar_Test;
```

Notice that `&macvar` contains `COMMENT` - even though that line appears to be commented out.

Macro comments are still processed by the macro tokenizer, though, so unmatched quotations can still be problematic, unless you use `/* */` style block comments.

Comment: That official SAS doc reference on [Macro comment Statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000543665.htm) is very useful. The example illustrates the difference between a standard `*commentary;` and `%*commentary` very clearly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a macro comment.

So this line, as written, will never execute

Answer (score 1):

It's just another way to comment:

From http://www.lexjansen.com/pharmasug/2002/proceed/TechTech/tt07.pdf

> Besides serving as the multiplication operator,
>   the asterisk is found in various places to indicate
>   interactions or cross-classification (such as the
>   TABLES statement in PROC FREQ) and in
>   indicating the number of times to repeat a
>   character string (as in PROC REPORT). **It is
>   used to comment statements alone or in
>   conjunction with the slash (/* … */) or the percent
>   sign (%**). The asterisk also compels SAS to
>   determine an array subscript by counting the
>   number of variables in the array. Two asterisks
>   indicate the exponentiation operator.

Comment: This doesn't correctly answer the question.  This is not 'just another comment', it has a purpose.